# Querying a specific blog instead of all blogs in Orchard

Tags: asp.net, orchardcms, blogs, orchardcms-1.7

How do I create a Query that display posts from a blog that I chose specifically? The built in Filter mechanism allows me to filter by Content Type only, which means that if I select Blog then it will query multiple blogs that I have.

I am using Orchard CMS 1.7 running on IIS server 7.5

Comment: You will have to build your own container filter, as there isn't one built into projections at this point. I think it's an oversight that I think should be fixed.

Comment: Is there such filter readily available somewhere on the web? It seems like quite a common problem and my gut feeling tells me someone must have done it/